# Blender behaves oddly on windows 10 suddenly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

On my Surface Book 2, Blender used to work alright. I know it's not the best hardware to render, but it's all I have.
Suddenly, I realized, Out of nowhere, the shading editor was acting strange. Connecting the shader nodes didn't work any more.
That's one example how I would like to see the nodes connected: https://pasteall.org/pic/ff4d203da1334027a0b167ab422d0f9d
But all I get is this:
https://pasteall.org/pic/bc0083e9a9474443b2d3b27c0f14f2e5
What's wrong?
you can find my Specs here: http://speccy.piriform.com/results/Nbwxaj5R2kdI4bteuwKSwqx

Comment: So you can't drag lines in between the nodes to connect them anymore?

Comment: please use the tools from this site to add images, so that they are displayed as part of the question and not as links. [how to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)